# Flash restart functions after completion

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, reset

I have made this code which works fine - my problem is that at the end i wish to make it start over.

When i started making this my intent was, that the .swf movie would just loop when it ended - but that does not happen. 
Then i figured that i would try and make a sort of "restart" function in the code itself that would reset the timer and strings.. 
I have googled around and tried a couple of things myself - But to no luck at all..

First i tried to reset the variable i. Then i tried to remove the timer eventListeners. But with no succes.

What would be the best way to go about getting this code to start over again?

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var str_one:String = 'På fredag udkommer metroXpress, som du kender den, for sidste gang... ';
var i:uint = 0;
var timer_one:Timer = new Timer(50);
timer_one.start();
timer_one.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goTime);

var str_two:String = 'På fredag udkommer metroXpress, som du kender den, for sidste gang... Fra 2. april bliver du mødt af en helt ny avis, med det bedste fra den gamle, tilsat en masse nyt.';
var timer_two:Timer = new Timer(50);
timer_two.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goTime_two);

var str_three:String = 'På fredag udkommer metroXpress, som du kender den, for sidste gang... Fra 2. april bliver du mødt af en helt ny avis, med det bedste fra den gamle, tilsat en masse nyt.Sådan vil vi skabe en endnu bedre avis til dig, der er på farten. Glæd dig – det gør vi!';
var timer_three:Timer = new Timer(50);
timer_three.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goTime_three);

function goTime(e:TimerEvent) {
    tekstbox1_txt.appendText(str_one.charAt(i));
    i++;
    if (i>=str_one.length) {
        timer_one.stop();
        TweenLite.to(hand, 1, {y:175, onComplete:ripwhite});
        }
    }

function ripwhite():void {
    TweenLite.to(hand, 1, {y:405});
    TweenLite.to(white_mask, 1, {y:320, onComplete:fadetekst1ud});
}

function fadetekst1ud():void {
    TweenLite.to(tekstbox1_txt, 1, {alpha:0, onComplete:tekstnr2});
    }

function tekstnr2():void {
timer_two.start();
}

function goTime_two(e:TimerEvent) {
    tekstbox2_txt.appendText(str_two.charAt(i));
    i++;
    if (i>=str_two.length) {
        timer_two.stop();
        TweenLite.to(tekstbox2_txt, 1, {alpha:1, onComplete:forsinkelse});
        }
    }

function forsinkelse():void {
    TweenLite.to(tekstbox2_txt, 1, {alpha:0, onComplete:tekstnr3});
    }

function tekstnr3():void {
timer_three.start();
}

function goTime_three(e:TimerEvent) {
    tekstbox3_txt.appendText(str_three.charAt(i));
    i++;
    if (i>=str_three.length) {
        timer_three.stop();
        TweenLite.to(tekstbox3_txt, 1, {alpha:1, onComplete:sidstefunktion});
        }
    }

function sidstefunktion():void {
    TweenLite.to(tekstbox3_txt, 1, {alpha:0});
    TweenLite.to(rippedpic, 1, {alpha:0});
    }
```

EDIT:

When setting up a reset function and then making it loop back to my initial function like this:

```
function nulstil():void {
    i = 0;
    TweenLite.killTweensOf(hand);
    TweenLite.killTweensOf(tekstbox1_txt);
    TweenLite.killTweensOf(tekstbox2_txt);
    TweenLite.killTweensOf(tekstbox3_txt);
    timer_one.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goTime);
    timer_two.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goTime_two);
    timer_two.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, goTime_three);
    TweenLite.to(white_mask, 0.1, {onComplete:goTimeAgain});
    }
```

I get the following in the output:

ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/goTimeAgain(). Expected 1, got 0.
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at com.greensock.core::TweenCore/complete()
    at com.greensock::TweenLite/renderTime()
    at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime()
    at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()

Comment: make a function that will be called at the end of the entire sequence which will reset all tha variables and mask sizes - and whatever you are changing in code.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I wonder how to reset tweens as they are, and how to drop ongoing tweens if any, if called by `TweenLite.to()`. Without this, the task might be impossible.

Comment: but how would you reset the variables?

Comment: e.g. `function reset():void { i = 0; /* more reset code here */}` then call `reset();` at last ticker animation

Comment: @Vesper to kill Tweens use:  TweenLite.killTweensOf(YourFuncOrObject);
Like TweenLite.killTweensOf(hand);

Comment: i tried the reset function with i = 0 - but it didnt seem to work - i will give the tweenkill ago - seperatly and combined and see if it makes a difference :-)=

Comment: Hi steffen -- Since you are already using GreenSock this seems like an ideal application for TimelineLite/TimelineMax. It will allow you to rewind and restart an entire heirarchy of Tweens without having to recreate them.

Comment: What does Joshua? :-)
I edited my question with some information of what happens when i try and do the reset function..

Comment: @steffenhenriksen I posted a full answer now showing how to use TimelineMax. By "It" I was referring to the TimelineMax instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggested in a comment that you use TimelineMax. Here's the full code that I think should work. Note carefully where I use the `offset` argument of `append` and where I don't. You'll need to fill out the `resetEverything` function to set all the visual elements to their proper starting positions, alphas, etc.

Basically how this works: Instead of using `Timers` we use the `addCallback` feature of TimelineMax. Callbacks have "length" of 0 in the timeline, so you have to manually advance the playhead when you are attaching the callbacks, and when you add the first tween after each batch of callbacks (that's where we use the offset argument). Tweens do have a length, though, so subsequent calls to `append` will automatically align the tweens to the end of the timeline as built up to the that point.

In the constructor of the TimelineMax we specified `repeat : -1`, which will cause the timeline to loop forever. Finally, we added the `resetEverything` callback at the very beginning so that every time the timeline restarts we are assured that all the elements are in the correct start position. The rest is completely automatic, handled by the timeline.

```
import com.greensock.*;

var str_one:String = 'På fredag udkommer metroXpress, som du kender den, for sidste gang... ';
var str_two:String = 'Fra 2. april bliver du mødt af en helt ny avis, med det bedste fra den gamle, tilsat en masse nyt.';
var str_three:String = 'Sådan vil vi skabe en endnu bedre avis til dig, der er på farten. Glæd dig – det gør vi!';

//-------- HELPER FUNCTIONS ---------//

// Set everything to start positions
function resetEverything():void {
    // Set alphas, positions, etc. 
    hand.x = <start x>;
    hand.y = <start y>;
    //
}

// Quick reusable callback
function addText(textBox:TextField, text:String):void { textBox.appendText(text); }

//-------- BUILD THE TIMELINE ---------//
var timeline:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax({repeat : -1}); //repeat = -1 --> loop forever
timeline.pause();
timeline.addCallback(resetEverything, 0);

var lng:uint = str_one.length;
var playHead:Number = 0.05;
for(var i:uint = 0; i < lng; i++) {
    timeline.addCallback(addText, playHead, [tekstbox1_txt, str_one.charAt(i)]);
    playHead += 0.05;
}
timeline.append(new TweenLite(hand, 1, {y:175}), lng * 0.05);  // !!Note the offset argument here!!
timeline.append(new TweenLite(hand, 1, {y:405}));
timeline.append(new TweenLite(white_mask, 1, {y:320}));
timeline.append(new TweenLite(tekstbox1_txt, 1, {alpha:0}));

playHead += 4;
lng = str_two.length;
for(i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
    timeline.addCallback(addText, playHead, [tekstbox2_txt, str_two.charAt(i)]);
    playHead += 0.05;
}
timeline.append(new TweenLite(tekstbox2_txt, 1, {alpha:1}), lng * 0.05); // !!Note the offset argument here!!
timeline.append(new TweenLite(tekstbox2_txt, 1, {alpha:0}));

playHead += 2;
lng = str_three.length;
for(i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
    timeline.addCallback(addText, playHead, [tekstbox3_txt, str_three.charAt(i)]);
    playHead += 0.05;
}
timeline.append(new TweenLite(tekstbox3_txt, 1, {alpha:1}), lng * 0.05); // !!Note the offset argument here!!
timeline.append(new TweenLite(tekstbox3_txt, 1, {alpha:0});
timeline.append(new TweenLite(rippedpic, 1, {alpha:0});

timeline.play();
```

Comment: function addText(textBox:TextField, text:String):void { textBox.appendText(text); } is giving an error with the semicolon and so is line 22 :-)

Line 28 returns this error invalid XML name - plus 4 other errors all connected to the XML tag..

Comment: Um, yeah, you'll have to replace "<start x>" and "<start y>" with the actual values you need!

Comment: i get this error: error 1067 implicit coercion of a value of type number to an unrelated type array in relations to line 34, 45 and 54 - Eg; timeline.addCallback(addText, [tekstbox2_txt, str_two.charAt(i)], playHead);

Comment: @steffenhenriksen Woops, I got the two arguments backwards. It should be `addCallback(addText, playHead, [txt*, str*.charAt(i)]);`. I've updated my code accordingly. See the [API documentation](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/_timelinemax.html).

Comment: Its works now - just a little clitch in that the text overlap eachother.. text two fading in before text one is fading out - is it some of the offset that i need to change or is it the arrangement of the lines?

Comment: @steffenhenriksen You might need to add a little more padding to the `lng * 0.05` parts; maybe `(lng * 0.05) + 0.5` or something...or maybe you need to add some offsets to the other `append` calls. A little tweaking and I'm sure you'll get it.

Comment: I thought as much :-) What is the timing of the lng * 0.05 is it milliseconds or?

Comment: Is there any way to make the tweens fire at the same time and not after each other? eg. with the hand and white_mask mc's?